# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded onload

Tags: javascript

I have a button on previous page which redirects to this page but the problem is when the page loads it doesn't show the confirm box. I get this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

</head>

//script

<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirm(){

        var con = confirm("Are You Sure?");

            if(con = true){
                window.location = "delete.php";

            }

        else{

            history.go(-1);

    }
        }

</script>

<body onload="confirm()">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always going to go back 1 page because you are not evaluating your condition correctly.

```
if (con = true) {
   window.location = "delete.php";
}
```

Should be

```
if (con == true) {
  window.location = "delete.php";
}
```

Note the additional `=`, `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is used to compare and evaluate the condition.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your javascript code:

1. You have named your function to be the same as the reserved function you are trying to call.
2. Your comparison is actually an assign

To fix the first problem, simply change the name of your function to something else like `confirmDeletion()`

```
<script>function confirmDeletion() { /* do stuff */ }</script>

<body onload="confirmDeletion()">
```

To fix the second problem, change the comparison. In javascript, the if statement automatically coerces the input into a boolean, meaning you don't actually need to compare it to `true`.

```
if (con) {
    /* do confirmed true stuff */
} else {
    /* do confirmed false stuff */
}
```

For future reference, make sure to always use triple equal `===` sign for comparison, otherwise you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you found my post useful, you could upvote it or mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your function from `confirm` to something else. The problem is that you're going into an infinite loop by calling `confirm` inside your `confirm` function.

So for example, this would work as I've renamed `confirm` to `myConfirm`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title></title>

</head>

//script

<script type="text/javascript">

function myConfirm(){

    var con = confirm("Are You Sure?");

        if(con = true){
            window.location = "delete.php";

        }

    else{

        history.go(-1);

}
    }

</script>

<body onload="myConfirm()">

</body>
```

**Edit**

Also change `con = true` to `con == true` to check if `con` is true rather than assigning it the value `true`.

Comment: i renamed it error is not coming but page is reloading again and again

Comment: I've added an edit that should fix the other "error" which is causing the page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the function. The condition, `if(con = true)`is assigning truthy value to `con` You should be comparing for truthy value like `if(con)`. You should be doing,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmNavigation(){

        var con = confirm("Are You Sure?");

            if(con){
                window.location = "delete.php";

            }

        else{

            history.go(-1);

    }
        }

</script>
```